# How do I modify my Yesod app during a test?

Tags: haskell, testing, yesod

I have a Yesod app with the type:

```
data App = App
    { appSettings    :: AppSettings
    , appStatic      :: Static
    , appConnPool    :: ConnectionPool
    , appHttpManager :: Manager
    , appLogger      :: Logger
    , appStripe      :: forall a. ((FromJSON (StripeReturn a)), Typeable (StripeReturn a))
                     => StripeConfig
                     -> StripeRequest a
                     -> IO (Either StripeError (StripeReturn a))
    }
```

and a helper function

```
stripe :: (FromJSON (StripeReturn a), Typeable (StripeReturn a))
       => StripeRequest a
       -> Handler (Either StripeError (StripeReturn a))
stripe req = do
  f <- appStripe <$> getYesod
  c <- appStripeConfig . appSettings <$> getYesod
  liftIO $ f c req
```

that is used in several handlers. (The `appStripe` field of the `App` is never referenced directly in any handlers.) In `makeFoundation`, everything is as scaffolded, except that the `appStripe` field is filled in with `Web.Stripe.stripe` from the `stripe-haskell` library.

In my tests, I would like to be able to mock the calls to Stripe, so I have the following function:

```
withStripeExpecting :: (FromJSON (StripeReturn a), Typeable (StripeReturn a))
                    => StripeRequest a
                    -> Either StripeError (StripeReturn a)
                    -> YesodExample App ()
                    -> YesodExample App ()
withStripeExpecting _expectedReq res = withStateT $ \yed -> yed {yedSite = f (yedSite yed)}
  where f app = app {appStripe = mock}
        mock :: Typeable (StripeReturn b)
             => StripeConfig
             -> StripeRequest b
             -> IO (Either StripeError (StripeReturn b))
        mock _ _actualReq = do
          -- assert actualReq matches expectedReq (in IO???)
          return $ case cast res of
                    Just a -> a
                    Nothing -> error "Stripe return types don’t match in mock."
```

which I use in test cases like:

```
spec :: Spec
spec = withApp $ do
  describe "create" $ do
    it "returns a 201" $ do
      -- a bunch of set-up elided
      withStripeExpecting stripeReq (Right stripeRes) $ do
        requestWithSubject "auth0|fake" $ do
          setMethod "POST"
          setUrl $ SubscriptionPlansR walletId
          setRequestBody encoded
          addRequestHeader (H.hContentType, "application/json")
        statusIs 201
```

which compiles and runs, but throws an error `StripeError {errorType = InvalidRequest, errorMsg = "Invalid API Key provided: ", errorCode = Nothing, errorParam = Nothing, errorHTTP = Just UnAuthorized}` suggesting that it is running the real stripe IO action instead of the mock.

How do I change a field of the `App` during a test so that it will be used by the handler under test?

Comment: Is the error happening with your withStripeExpecting block or withApp initialisation ? I would suggest to modify the withApp function (which is scaffolded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a reference to this question on the Google Group for Yesod, and received [this response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/yesodweb/s8Azk8_8S8A/zAVvgl6-CAAJ) from Michael Snoyman, the originator of Yesod:

> IIUC, you just need to override the field at a different spot in the code. Using the scaffolded site as an example, I'd override here:
>
> https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod-scaffold/blob/68ec6af22248de6c2a00e63624c34350846557cf/test/TestImport.hs#L35

Following that advice necessitated some rework to the `Yesod.Test` module to thread control of the mocks through to the test case. Those changes have been captured in [Pull Request #1274](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/pull/1274) to the yesod repo on GitHub.

With the modified version of yesod-test in place, I was able to replace the line noted by Michael Snoyman with the following three lines:

```
mocks <- newEmptyMVar
let foundation' = foundation { appStripe = mockStripe mocks }
return (foundation', logWare, mocks)
```

I also added the following supporting definitions to the `TestImport` module:

```
data StripeMock = forall a. Typeable (StripeReturn a)
               => StripeMock
                { stripeReq :: StripeRequest a
                , stripeRet :: Either StripeError (StripeReturn a)
                }

type Mocks = MVar StripeMock

type Yex = YesodExample App Mocks

mockStripe :: (Typeable (StripeReturn b))
           => Mocks
           -> StripeConfig
           -> StripeRequest b
           -> IO (Either StripeError (StripeReturn b))
mockStripe mocks _ _actualReq = do
  (StripeMock _expectedReq res) <- takeMVar mocks
  -- assert actualReq matches expectedReq (in IO???)
  return $ case cast res of
            Just a -> a
            Nothing -> error "Stripe return types don’t match in mock."

stripeExpects :: (FromJSON (StripeReturn a), Typeable (StripeReturn a))
              => StripeRequest a
              -> Either StripeError (StripeReturn a)
              -> Yex ()
stripeExpects expectedReq res = do
  mocks <- getMocks
  putMVar mocks $ StripeMock expectedReq res
```

The `stripeExpects` helper function replaces `withStripeExpecting`, and doesn’t wrap the request the way `withStripeExpecting` did.

As indicated in the pull request, I’m trying to get this capacity included in the yesod-test package. If I get traction on that, I’ll update this answer.